# What kind of pros and cons involve with headless selenium test execution

Tags: selenium, webdriver

What kind of pros and con involve with headless selenium test execution. I would like to know the recommendations to run tests on real browser vs headless browsers

Answer (score 1):

With a real browser you can; see whats actually going on, inspect element, test javascript on the go. 
With a headless browser you can let it run in the background.

But they are both very similar. One you can see... the other you cant.

I traditionally develop using selenium with a browser to see whats going on, and if your code implements a webdriver interface you can just switch browser whenever you want.... even to go headless.

In c# you have RemoteWebDriver, which is what you want to use if you want to be able to use different browsers.